# Scala generics with <: and multiple traits

Tags: scala, generics, traits

A nearly unknown feature of Java is this generics syntax:

```
public class Baz<T extends Foo & Bar> {}
```

I would like to do the same in Scala but I don't know how to do it, can someone give me the syntax please?

I had previously:

```
class MongoObject[T <: CaseClass]
```

And now i need:

```
class MongoObject[T <: IdentifiableModel & CaseClass]
```

Or at least something similar

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `with` keyword just as you would in an extends clause:

```
class MongoObject[T <: IdentifiableModel with CaseClass]
```

This means that `T` has to be a subtype of `IdentifiableModel` and `CaseClass`.

Comment: @SebastienLorber thanks for accepting the answer, now I have 13333 reputation points :D